# How to make zsh ignore undefined escape sequences?

Tags: zsh, key-binding

Is there a way to make zsh ignore all undefined escape sequences, including things like `F1` which is `^[[15~` and usually causes a `~` to be inserted.

To be more precise, I'd like all characters that are sent to the terminal <= `$KEYTIMEOUT` hundreds of a second after an escape character is sent to be ignored unless they are part of a bound key sequence.